# JavaScript active class on menu items

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I have the following `html` and `JavaScript` to add an active class called `is-active` to a menu item `onClick`. When you click on another item it gets removed from the previous one and gets added to the current one. My code is as follows which I got from **W3Schools**. I wanted to know if there is a better and more modern way of writing the JavaScript. **(NO jQuery)** only plain vanilla JavaScript

**HTML:**

```
<div class="our-clients__categories">
   <a href="#technology" class="our-clients__categories--category is-active"><h4>Technology</h4></a>
   <a href="#retail" class="our-clients__categories--category"><h4>Retail</h4></a>
   <a href="#finance" class="our-clients__categories--category"><h4>Finance</h4></a>
   <a href="#consumer" class="our-clients__categories--category"><h4>Consumer</h4></a>
   <a href="#hospitality" class="our-clients__categories--category"><h4>Hospitality</h4></a>
 </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
export default function () {
  const clientCategoryButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.our-clients__categories--category')

  clientCategoryButtons.forEach((categorybtn) => {
    categorybtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()

      const current = document.getElementsByClassName('is-active')

      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace('is-active', '')
      this.className += ' is-active'
    })
  })
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated! :)

Comment: You can replace `document.getElementsByClassName('is-active')` with `document.querySelector('.is-active')` (just returns the first matching element, so no need for `current[0]` - just use `current`).  Also, I **hate** the use of string replace to remove a class.  What if I came along and added a class of `this-active`?  Have a look at `classList` here... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: shot @Archer gonna give this a try :)

Comment: I realised after I'd posted my comment that just saying I hate something isn't constructive.  I've edited it to offer an alternative.

Comment: Thanks @Archer I replaced `document.getElementsByClassName('is-active')` with `querySelector`. What would you suggest to replace the .replace method?

Comment: I put a link in my comment above for that.

Comment: Incidentally, this question would be more suited here... https://codereview.stackexchange.com